# Multiple aws ec2 instances results in poor communication with s3 buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have an overarching Bash script where there are 3 main processes that are executed within the script:

1. Spin up an ec2 instance (lets say ec2-1) which will pull data from a private s3 bucket (in the same region: us-east-1) and run some programs.
2. Spin up an ec2 instance (lets say ec2-2) which will pull data from a public amazon s3 bucket (in the same region: us-east-1) and run some programs.
3. Spin up an ec2 instance (lets say ec2-3) which will pull data from a private s3 bucket (separate from 1), but still in region: us-east-1) and run some programs.

To ensure that each, individual process worked, I ran them all separately. For example, in my bash script, I would run only process 1) and ensure it completes from start-to-finish. After that completes, I would test 2), wait for this to run through completely, and then test 3) to ensure that runs through completely. Everything works fine, and have it all working well. Download speeds are in excess of 25-30 MB/s, which is perfect since a lot of data is being moved to/from s3 buckets.

Now I am at the stage where I attempt to run 1, 2, and 3 together all within the same Bash script. Note: all three ec2 instances SHOULD be independent from one another as they all have their own unique instance-id but are all in the same region (us-east-1). However, when I run all 3 at once, there is something that causes download speeds to/from the s3 buckets to become VERY slow - from ~ 25MB/s to 1 kB/s, and sometimes even completely stopping. It is interesting because 1) and 3) are pulling data from a private bucket, whereas 2) is pulling data from Amazon's public s3 bucket, yet ALL THREE instances have slow/stopped download speeds. I have even increased all of the three ec2 instances to m5dn.24xlarge, and the download speeds are still abysmal.

I also tried to run two separate instances of 1), 2), or 3), and they perform slower as well. For example, if I run 1) for two separate dates (with two separate instance-id's), the speed is lower compared to if I just run one instance of 1).

My question is: how/why would this be happening? Any feedback / info would be very helpful.

Comment: Are they all sharing any sort of resource like a common database or something? From only the information you have provided, this problem should not be happening, so there has to be more to the picture.

Comment: Exactly my point - something must be happening. Apart from sharing every line of my code(s), there isn't a common database (from my knowledge). One s3 bucket is hosted publicly from amazon, and the other two are part of an overall private s3 bucket with a hierarchy such as: s3://topdir/dir1 and s3://topdir/dir2

Comment: Where are you running the bash script? In your local machine? When you say you are running all 3 together, you mean you are just running 3 processes in your local machine each running the entire script or did you modify your script to internally create threads and run the 3 methods? Such a major decrease in performance has got to do with faulty configuration of EC2 and not because the S3 bucket is being shared or something.

Comment: The bash script is on my local machine which can directly communicate with the s3 buckets / ec2 instances. I created a functions in the bash script, where function it calls the 'aws ec2 run-instances' command to create a unique ec2 instance, and then run the 'aws ssm send-command' to copy a script from the s3 bucket to the newly created ec2 instance, and then a final 'aws ssm send-command' to run the script on the newly created ec2 instance. This is then repeated for the other 2 ec2 instances, but is done in series, not parallel to ensure no mixup of instance-id's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was an endpoint was not setup correctly so communication was lacking.